# Temporary label

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a label covering up a g.i.f I want to show after a button is pressed for 
a certain amount of time like 1000 m/1 second and then hide it again after the time is over. How do you do that?
(I know how to make the label visible(true/false) when you click th button bet not for a period of time)

Comment: Try using a timer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx), [await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx), and [Task.Delay()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh139096(v=vs.110).aspx) all from the Button handler itself:

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        label1.Visible = true;

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); // whatever time delay you need in here

        label1.Visible = false;
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }
```